# apache mod_proxy ProxyPassReverse Location header

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, mod-proxy

I have tomcat behind apache with the following setup:

```
ServerName someapp.com

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/someapp/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/someapp/
```

Everything works fine until tomcat response header contains something like:

```
Location: /someapp/foo
```

It causes 404 or 500 because the browser goes to "http://someapp.com/someapp/foo" instead of "http://someapp.com/foo/"

What i did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because ProxyPassReverse will replace the Location which your server returned.
In your case, you can see example 1.

### Example 1 (Only URL Path)

Apache2 Setting

```
ProxyPass "/8080" "http://localhost:8080"
ProxyPassReverse "/8080/" "/"
```

Node.js Setting

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({a: 8080})
})

app.get("/hi", (req, res) => {
    res.json({a: "8080hi"})
})

app.get("/redirect", (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/hi")
})

app.listen(8080)
```

Original Location is "Location: /hi".
New one is "Location: /8080/hi". (/ => /8080/)

That means Apache2 replaced the Location value with ProxyPassReverse setting.
Or you can use full FQDN to do it.

### Example 2 (FQDN)

Apache2 Setting

```
ProxyPass "/8080" "http://localhost:8080"
ProxyPassReverse "/8080" "http://localhost:8080"
```

Node.js Setting

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({a: 8080})
})

app.get("/hi", (req, res) => {
    res.json({a: "8080hi"})
})

app.get("/redirect", (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader("Location", "http://localhost:8080/hi")
    res.send(302)
})

app.listen(8080)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure this is the best way, but for now found the only fix with mod header:

```
Header edit Location ^/someapp/ http://someapp.com/
```